# Calling UITABLEVIEW in other implementation IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a View Controller named as `MasterViewController` having a `tableView` implemented in it (as a part of my module). It contains following methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Now I want to integrate my Module in My Main Project named as  "myProject" having its view controller `ViewController`.

How Can I `init` my `MasterViewController` in `ViewController` i.e call its `init` method. My current approach is only loading `(void)viewDidLoad` method and showing empty table view in my `ViewController` keeping in view that my `MasterViewController` have an **interface builder** of `storyboard` named as `Main`

**My Approach:**

```
 MasterViewController* mainVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] init]; 
            [self.view insertSubview:mainVC.view belowSubview:tabBar];
```

Comment: Easy solution if using storyboard: in storyboard viewController scene you add. Inside its view, add viewcontroller widget and assign MasterViewController as a class. IBOutlet this MasterViewController widget to ViewController.h file.

Comment: You have to use UIView containment to add the subview, that is the preferred way to do it and you can do it in storyboard or in code.

Comment: @Mrunal I'm not getting exactly, how to add "its view". Please explain me in more detail.

Comment: Like you add UIButton in a scene, add a UIViewController to your class ViewController's scene.

Comment: @k6sandeep How can I use containment, please answer me in more detail.

Comment: @Mrunal I'm currently doing this,  I've a tabbar, and  calling method `didSelectedItem` and `item.tag` in switch operation to get the button clicked. After geting, I want to init that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in viewDidLoad of ViewController class add the following;

In Viewcontroll.h:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 ..... 

    MasterViewController *MSVC = (MasterViewController * )[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
   [self addChildViewController:MSVC];
   [self.view addSubview:MSVC.view];

.....
}
```

Note that you have to call both addChildViewController and addSubview in order for your child view to display. You should not init your MasterViewController in your ViewController's init method.

Comment: Giving error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: Do you also need to call didMoveToParentViewController: after adding thr child ?

Comment: user3166680: That is the problem in your array object. Not the view controller's. for K6z: that's is the delegate method you don't need to call in this case. Unless you want to add further implementation when you view controller is added. See below thread for the delegate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909788/what-exactly-willmovetoparentviewcontroller-and-didmovetoparentviewcontroller