# didMoveToParentViewController and willMoveToParentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

Apple Documentation on `UIViewController` says:

If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the `willMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller before calling the `removeFromParentViewController` method, passing in a parent value of nil.

When your custom container calls the `addChildViewController:` method, it automatically calls the `willMoveToParentViewController`: method of the view controller to be added as a child before adding it.

If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or, if there is no transition, immediately after calling the `addChildViewController:` method.

The `removeFromParentViewController` method automatically calls the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller after it removes the child.

Why should I call these methods? What does those methods do?

```
ProfileViewController *profile = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
profile.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:profile];
[self.view addSubview:profile.view];
[profile didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

My code works perfectly even though I remove the last line. Can someone please help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These methods just use for some situations. After/before you move/remove a viewcontroller to/from viewcontroller. If juts add/ push/ remove/ pop, you don't have to call it.

Comment: Removing those methods do not show any change. Same is the case with adding them too

Comment: Yes. It's right. This method doesn't do anything. Just the call of didMoveToParentViewController method. If you don't implement it, call it -> don't do anything.

Comment: Will it do anything for memory management?

Comment: Not. You can ignore it.

Comment: So, what is the point to use them if there is no affect, and they could be ignored?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These methods are used because it is a rule to be followed when adding or removing a child view controller. Before adding a child view controller `willMoveToParentViewController` method should be called first followed by `didMoveToParentViewController` method. While removing child view controller from parent view controller these methods are to be called in reverse order.

`addChildViewController:` automatically calls `[child willMoveToParentViewController:self]`. So one should call `didMoveToParentViewController` after `addChildViewController:`. Similarly `removeFromParentViewController:` automatically calls `[child didMoveToParentViewController:nil]`. So one should call `willMoveToParentViewController:` before `removeFromParentViewController:`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, they don't do anything that you can notice in the interface. "However, any subclass allows them to be overridden, so if you don't call them, you won't break a bare UIViewController, but you will break subclasses that rely on it (for instance: say a subclass wants to release an object when it is removed from a parent view controller, if you don't call the method, then it will never release the object)." as it was explained in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909788/what-exactly-willmovetoparentviewcontroller-and-didmovetoparentviewcontroller).